# mongodb journal redundancy (prevent journal loss)

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to configure multiple journal groups in MongoDB to prevent journal loss in case of a disk failure?

If it doesn't make sense please explain why this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to configure multiple journals. Usually, protecting against disk failure is done with RAID setup, not with a MongoDB configuration. However, having a machine running in a replica set also helps protect the data as a whole from problems with any one member.

Comment: How does Replica Set provide protection against journal loss? Does it write to the journals on ALL instances in the replica set at the same time?